Anyone have any idea what if anything is behind the concrete block walls?
I'm trying to mount a few hose reels around the house.  I'm assuming next the main breaker and above the cable stuff should be good as there is drywall after the concrete block and I assume the wires would be in there.  The water main is where I'm most concerned as there is just that one concrete block that it is going into and I don't know where it goes from there.



Most concrete block, stuff goes straight though, from inside to outside, as that is the easiest.  Drywall on wood studs inside might be different, so know what is inside.

Yea I’m going about 1 3/4 in. The main water supply had no drywall behind it and I the other side of the wall has no pipes so I assume it’s in there. Don’t know if it goes sideways. Straight up or whatever

Odd.  You know how much space is inside blocks, so hard to think they would go in blocks.

use strong magnet to find out

This can depend on where you are located. In the southeast plenty of times the water lines go in the wall and down through the concrete slab.

Yes my neighbor said he believes it goes down so I’m good to go
